# What error to raise with wrong post request body?

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and have an endpoint that accepts post requests. The endpoint expects a specific set of keys in the post request body. **What type of Exception should I raise if they don't provide the right keys?** `ValueError`? Thanks!

Comment: Use https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#validationerror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return a [`HttpResponseBadRequest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseBadRequest) response and include a helpful message with the invalid data. This returns a 400 response which is used to indicate issues with request data

If you are creating rest endpoints with Django it is worth using a library like https://www.django-rest-framework.org/ as it can simplify their creation and handle a lot of the leg work around validation, serialisation and reponses

Comment: Thanks for this response! I actually am using django rest framework! Is there a different response I should do if I am using it? Thanks!

Comment: If you are using serializers correctly then the serializer will raise a ValidationError when you validate the data passed to it which the rest framework with catch and then return a 400 response for you

Comment: @NickSmith might be easier to help if you add the code for your view/endpoint

Comment: Wait... I am new to DRF, but this is a custom endpoint that takes in some data, does a bunch of pre-processing on it and spits something else out. I have just been using `api_view` and returning `Response()`... is there a better way?

Comment: The class-based views offer a lot more functionality than the function based views, I would recommend using those as they remove the need for a lot of boilerplate code and give the ability to use mixins/inheritance